# "Decimal" flags (instead of binary) - built-in way?

Tags: c#, flags

I have this formula which I got from some documentation, which is supposed to explain what a "Flags" integer represents:

`Flags = Spectator * 1 + TemporarySpectator * 10 + PureSpectator * 100 + AutoTarget * 1000 + CurrentTargetId * 10000`

I wrote this code which is able to convert a number (flags) to some booleans + one integer, just like in the formula:

```cs
////////// From Values to Flag //////////

bool Spectator          = true;
bool TemporarySpectator = false;
bool PureSpectator      = true;
bool AutoTarget         = false;
int  CurrentTargetId    = 255;

int Calculate() =>
    (Convert.ToInt32(Spectator)          * 1) +
    (Convert.ToInt32(TemporarySpectator) * 10) +
    (Convert.ToInt32(PureSpectator)      * 100) +
    (Convert.ToInt32(AutoTarget)         * 1000) +
    (Convert.ToInt32(CurrentTargetId)    * 10000);

int Result = Calculate(); // 2550101


////////// From Flag to Values //////////

CurrentTargetId      = Convert.ToInt32(Result / 10000);
AutoTarget           = Convert.ToBoolean((Result - (CurrentTargetId * 10000)) / 1000);
PureSpectator        = Convert.ToBoolean((Result - (CurrentTargetId * 10000) - (Convert.ToInt32(AutoTarget) * 1000)) / 100);
TemporarySpectator   = Convert.ToBoolean((Result - (CurrentTargetId * 10000) - (Convert.ToInt32(AutoTarget) * 1000) - (Convert.ToInt32(PureSpectator) * 100)) / 10);
Spectator            = Convert.ToBoolean((Result - (CurrentTargetId * 10000) - (Convert.ToInt32(AutoTarget) * 1000) - (Convert.ToInt32(PureSpectator) * 100) - (Convert.ToInt32(TemporarySpectator) * 100)) / 1);

Result = Calculate(); // 2550101
```

As you can see, my code is also able to do the reverse operation too - which is converting values to a flag.

Fiddle of my code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ua2wi8

Does this kind of operation have any name? I know about the `FlagsAttribute` for enums which is similar but stores flags as individual bits ("binary digits") instead of decimal digits like in my case.

Is there any easier or even native way to do this in C#? Using booleans right from a model class would be a plus.

Comment: `does this kind of operation have any name?` - "inconvenient bit shifting"?

Comment: @GSerg I agree it is pretty inconvenient. However, I'm just following some documentation for an old game that some people wrote more than 15 years ago :D

Comment: @Matt for future questions please put title that makes sense for the topic you want to ask about rather than generic (and thus useless for actual users of the site - future visitors) text like "help me", "is there bug in my code", "is there easier way to do it". (I've edited title in a way I think aligns with your question - feel free to improve that)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Will do! Thanks a lot for the nice edit, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I think you need to look into the `%` (modulus) operator.

Comment: There are programming languages that don't have bit manipulation operators. Or there are programmers who don't understand them. Either way, there are many ways to implement bit operations badly. The worst I've seen is turning an int into a binary string and back again, in a language with a modulus operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it, with manual string parsing:

```cs
public class SpectatorStatus : IFlag
{
    public SpectatorStatus(int value)
    {
        var valueStr = value.ToString("D7");

        const char True = '1';

        CurrentTargetId = Convert.ToInt32(valueStr[..3]);
        AutoTarget = valueStr[3] == True;
        PureSpectator = valueStr[4] == True;
        TemporarySpectator = valueStr[5] == True;
        Spectator = valueStr[6] == True;
    }

    public bool Spectator { get; }
    public bool TemporarySpectator { get; }
    public bool PureSpectator { get; }
    public bool AutoTarget { get; }
    public int CurrentTargetId { get; }

    public override string ToString()
        => (Convert.ToInt32(Spectator)
            + Convert.ToInt32(TemporarySpectator) * 10
            + Convert.ToInt32(PureSpectator) * 100
            + Convert.ToInt32(AutoTarget) * 1000
            + CurrentTargetId * 10000)
            .ToString("D7");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FlagsAttribute` for enums just controls how an enum will print when using `ToString`, and it will list out all values in a nice comma-separated list.

What you are trying to do can be achieved by enums (optimally), but also can be achieved by using ints if you understand binary, or powers of 2.

##### Using Enum

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Spectator          = 1 << 0,    // 1 or 2^0
    TemporarySpectator = 1 << 1,    // 2 or 2^1
    PureSpectator      = 1 << 2,    // 4 or 2^2
    AutoTarget         = 1 << 3,    // 8 or 2^3
    CurrentTargetId    = 1 << 4     // 16 or 2^4
}

MyEnum flags =  MyEnum.Spectator | MyEnum.PureSpectator | MyEnum.CurrentTargetId;

////////// Extracting individual values from flags //////////

MyEnum currentTargetId      = flags & MyEnum.CurrentTargetId;
MyEnum autoTarget           = flags & MyEnum.AutoTarget;
MyEnum pureSpectator        = flags & MyEnum.PureSpectator;
MyEnum temporarySpectator   = flags & MyEnum.TemporarySpectator;
MyEnum spectator            = flags & MyEnum.Spectator;

if (flags.HasFlag(MyEnum.AutoTarget))
{
    // Do Stuff
}

if (flags.HasFlag(MyEnum.Spectator))
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

##### Using Pure Ints

```
const int spectator            = 0b_0000_0001;    // 1 or 2^0
const int temporarySpectator   = 0b_0000_0010;    // 2 or 2^1
const int pureSpectator        = 0b_0000_0100;    // 4 or 2^2
const int autoTarget           = 0b_0000_1000;    // 8 or 2^3
const int currentTargetId      = 0b_0001_0000;    // 16 or 2^4

int flags =  spectator | pureSpectator | currentTargetId;

////////// Extracting individual values from flags //////////

int currentTargetIdVal      = flags & currentTargetId;
int autoTargetVal           = flags & autoTarget;
int pureSpectatorVal        = flags & pureSpectator;
int temporarySpectatorVal   = flags & temporarySpectator;
int spectatorVal            = flags & spectator;

if ((flags & autoTarget) > 0)
{
    // Do Stuff
}

if ((flags & spectator) > 0)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

C# also allows for using [Binary Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/binary-literals), so `MyEnum` can also be written as so:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    Spectator          = 0b_0000_0001,
    TemporarySpectator = 0b_0000_0010,
    PureSpectator      = 0b_0000_0100,
    AutoTarget         = 0b_0000_1000,
    CurrentTargetId    = 0b_0001_0000
}
```

Comment: For anyone who wants arguably better looking code, one can use  [Enum.HasFlag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag) (eg.  `isSpectator = flags.HasFlag(MyEnum.Spectator)`)

Comment: @ErikPhilips For a boolean result, yes always use `HasFlag`. I took the OPs intent as receiving the integer value (in this case the enum value) representation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the nice reply! However, we have to consider that `CurrentTargetId` is an integer - How to deal with that then? As this doesn't fit into an enum

Comment: @matt all [enum are integers unless otherwise specfied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum).  So is 255 static or does it actually change?

Comment: @Matt, building off of Erik's comment, `255` would be equal to `1 << 8`

Comment: @ErikPhilips Sorry, that's not what I meant. How can I use a custom value for `CurrentTargetId `? Example with a value of 255: `MyEnum flags =  MyEnum.Spectator | MyEnum.PureSpectator | 255;` (pseudo-code) - Also, how can I then convert `flags` to an integer and get something like 2550101 out of it? (Like in my example)

Comment: @Matt, please re-read both Erik's and my comment. `CurrentTarget = 255` is a valid enum value. To convert flags to an `int` simply cast it as so: `int f = (int)flags;`

Comment: @Matt if `CurrentTargetId` changes, you can remove it from the enum and simply just add the two where necessary. `int f = CurrentTarget + (int)flags;`. Also refer to my answer where I recreated all the logic using pure integers

Comment: @Matt `int i = 255;` = `int i = 1 << 8;` = `int i = 0b10000000;` = `int i = 0xFF;`

Comment: @maksymiuk This doesn't seem to give the correct result, even when multiplying `CurrentTargetId` by 10000 - See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p7vyxK - Am I missing on something?

Comment: @Matt, why are you multiplying by 10000?

Comment: @maksymiuk Isn't that required when manually doing an addition to the enum? See my fiddle. Anyway, it doesn't seem to work with or without the multiplication, even tho with it the result could look realistic, even tho it's wrong

Comment: @Matt, you asked about an easier and native way. The native 'easier' way involves not having to do useless operations. If you explain to me the *purpose* behind what you are trying to accomplish exactly then I can help you out.

Comment: @maksymiuk What I'm trying to accomplish is exactly what your class does (and it does it just fine!) - I'll be accepting it as the answer soon if there's no cleaner way to do it via enums

Comment: Enums isn't really an answer, since there's no clean way to translate between the game's representation (which is in decimal), and the enum form (which is in binary).  You would end up messing with divisions and modulos anyway.

Comment: @RoadieRich OP was asking about an easier or 'native' way of accomplishing flags. The purpose here would be to *replace* the game's inferior flag logic with the native flag capability of integers and enums.

Comment: @maksymiuk It sounds like the OP doesn't have access to change the code in the game for the "inferior" flag logic.

Comment: @RoadieRich That is right, I do not.

Comment: @Matt, Ok I'll have another answer incoming then I think I understand better your *purpose*

Answer (score 0):

You could probably wrap it all in a class, and use the modulo operator to simplify things:

```
class DecimalFlags
{
    private int _value = 0;
    public bool Spectator
    {
        get
        {
            return _value % 10 == 1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && _value % 10 != 1) _value += 1;
            else if (_value % 10 == 1) _value -= 1;
        }
    }

    public bool TemporarySpectator
    {
        get
        {
            return (_value/10) % 10 == 1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && (_value/10) % 10 != 1) _value += 10;
            else if ((_value/10) % 10 == 1) _value -= 10;
        }
    }

    public bool PureSpectator
    {
        get
        {
            return (_value / 100) % 10 == 1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && (_value / 100) % 10 != 1) _value += 100;
            else if ((_value / 100) % 10 == 1) _value -= 100;
        }
    }

    public bool AutoTarget
    {
        get
        {
            return (_value / 1000) % 10 == 1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && (_value / 1000) % 10 != 1) _value += 1000;
            else if ((_value / 1000) % 10 == 1) _value -= 1000;
        }
    }
    
    public int CurrentTargetId {get;set;}
    
    public static explicit operator int(DecimalFlags df)
    {
        return df._value + df.CurrentTargetId*10000;
    }
    public static explicit operator DecimalFlags(int i)
    {
        var df = new DecimalFlags();
        df.CurrentTargetId = i/10000;
        df._value = i - df.CurrentTargetId*10000;
        return df;
    }
}
```

Then when you need to pass your value back to the game you can say

```
MyGameFunction((int)decimalFlags);
```

Or receiving the value from the game:

```
int value = GetValueFromGame();
var decimalFlags = (DecimalFlags)value;
bool isSpectator = decimalFlags.Spectator; //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own struct object to represent the flags. This struct shown below will store all your flags *and* your `CurrentTaregtId` in 8 bytes, or the size of a `long`. You can then use the `.Calculate` function to get the value your looking for in decimal. All these flags can have values up to `255`, whereas the shortcoming of the decimal system was each value could only hold up to `9` to be used as a proper 'flag'.

Keep in mind that this code is **not yet tested**. So *minor* alterations may be required.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MyFlags {

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong Value;
    
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Spectator;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte TemporarySpectator;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte PureSpectator;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte AutoTarget;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public uint CurrentTargetId;
    
    public MyFlags(in ulong value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    
    public MyFlags(in byte spectator, in byte temporarySpectator, in byte pureSpectator, in byte autoTarget, in uint currentTargetId) {
        Spectator = spectator;
        TemporarySpectator = temporarySpectator;
        PureSpectator = pureSpectator;
        AutoTarget = autoTarget;
        CurrentTargetId = currentTargetId;
    }
    
    public long Calculate()
    {
        return Spectator
            + TemporarySpectator * 10
            + PureSpectator * 100
            + AutoTarget * 1000
            + CurrentTargetId * 10000;
    }
}

/// Usage

MyFlags flags = new MyFlags();
flags.TemporarySpectator = 4;
flags.PureSpectator = 7;
flags.CurrentTargetId = 255;
flags.Calculate();

if (flags.AutoTarget > 0)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```